# Find field is of which class, parent or child in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, parent-child

Can somebody help on this?

I have class. This is just demo, in actual I have more fields.

```
public class ParentData
{
   private String field2 = "";
}

public class Data extends ParentData
{
   private String field1 = "";
}
```

Implementation of getAllFieldsofParentAndChildClass method

```
public Field[] getAllFieldsofParentAndChildClass(Class<?> clazz)
{
   Field[] childFields = null;
   Field[] parentFields = null;
   Field[] allFields = null;

   childFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

   if(clazz.getSuperclass() != null)
   {
       parentFields = clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
       allFields = Arrays.copy(childFields, childFields.length + parentFields.length);
       System.arraycopy(parentFields, 0, allFields, childFields.length, parentFields.length);
   }
   else
   {
      allFields = Arrays.copy(childFields, childFields.length);
    }

    return allFields;
}
```

```
Field[] allFields = getAllFieldsofParentAndChildClass(Data.class);

// allFields contains all fields of parent and child class.

for(Field field : allFields)
{
   String className = field.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();  //Line 5
   String fieldName = field.getName();

   String parentClass = field.getDeclaringClass().getSuperClass().getSimpleName();  //Line 8

   String actualClassName = //Some magic code

   System.out.println("Field Name: " + fieldName + "ClassName: " + actualClassName);

// More code using java reflection
}
```

I want output like this:

```
Field Name: field1 ClassName: Data
Field Name: field2 ClassName: ParentData
```

I hope I'm more clear now

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you explain more what you are actually trying to do?  I don't think you can do what you want from the code you have.  How much flexibility do you have with the above code?  Could you start with a list of objects instead of fields?

Comment: @markspace, I'm flexible with the code, here I just written an approach which I'm using, if there is some other better way to achieve this, I'll use that.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with the object (or the class object) you can just get the fields for each class and parent class:

```
public class ReflectionRecursion {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      printFields( new ParentData() );
      printFields( new Data() );
   }

   private static void printFields( Object o ) {
      for( Class<?> type = o.getClass(); type != Object.class; type = type.getSuperclass() ) {
         System.out.println( type );
         Field[] fields = type.getDeclaredFields();
         for( Field field : fields ) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            System.out.println( "    " + fieldName );
         }
      }
   }

}

class ParentData {
   private String field2 = "";
}

class Data extends ParentData {
   private String field1 = "";
}
```

Edit: here's a new method to match your new improved output specification.

```
   private static void printFields( Object o ) {
      for( Class<?> type = o.getClass(); type != Object.class; type = type.getSuperclass() ) {
         Field[] fields = type.getDeclaredFields();
         for( Field field : fields ) {
            System.out.println( "Field name: " + field.getName() 
                    + " Class name: " + type.getSimpleName());
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't want to just print fieldName, I want it's class also(if it is declared in child class, then childclassname, if it is declared in parent class, then parent class name).

Comment: I matched your output specification exactly.  I think you should review your question more carefully.

Comment: `getDeclaringClass()` might be what you're after.

Comment: it worked with the above code with this change. Instead of using ```getAllFieldsofParentAndChildClass(Class<?> clazz)```, I used ```getAllFieldsofParentAndChildClass(Object o)``` and I got the parent class name for ```field2``` and pardon me for continuous edits to my question

Answer (score -1):

If you are ok with using reflection, then you could use getDeclaredFields method available in reflection to get fields from Super class or child class as shown below

```
Field[] parentFields = Data.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
Field[] childFields = Data.class.getDeclaredFields();
Field[] allFields = new Field[parentFields.length + childFields.length];
```

For more detailed explanation please refer --> https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-class-fields